# Add multiple mock modules in one test with 'addMockModule'

Tags: angularjs, protractor, httpbackend, ngmocke2e

I'm mocking some end-points on an Angular website with Protractor using the following pattern:

```
// mock.js
// adding the mock module and passing it data
Mock.prototype.all = {
    default: function() {
      browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', mockModules.all, {
        data: data
      })
    }
}

// mockmodules.js
// add dependencies to module and inject it
exports.all = function() {

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/user/).respond(function() {
        return [200, data.mockData.data];
    });    

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();

    angular.module('httpBackendMock' ['ngMockE2E', 'sportsbook-app'])
        .value('data', {
            'mockData': arguments[0],
            'count': 0
        })
        .run(runBlock);
        runBlock.$inject = ['$httpBackend', 'data', 'eventDataSourceManager'];  
}

// test-spec.js
// call mock from test
it("Mock", function() {

    mock.all.default();
});
```

Now this works fine, but I want to be able to add more modules by having multiple modules that all send different data. Example:

```
Mock.prototype.all = {
    default: function() {
      browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', mockModules.allDefault, {
        data: data
      })
    },
    user: function() {
      browser.addMockModule('user', mockModules.allUser, {
        userData: userData
      })
    }
}

it("Mock", function() {

    mock.all.default();
    mock.all.user();
});
```

Like this, none of the mocks seem to be working.

Also within the selenium server I can see that both modules' names are being found:

```
Executing: [execute script: angular.resumeBootstrap(arguments[0]);, [[protractorBaseModule_, httpBackendMock, user]]])
```

At first I thought the issue was with

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
$httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();
```

Tried adding this to a separate module and call it after all other modules are called, but still it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended, because both of your mock modules use the same module name identifier, `httpBackendMock`. You could use a unique name and then the latest module would not override the others.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. The allDefault and allUser page objects infact have a unique module name identifier, example: angular.module('allU') and angular.module('allD'). Edited the main question to reflect this. Still can't figure out what the issue might be... I was also wrong that only the last mock was working, in reality they both don't work (last one was working when I tested with same module names)